# How does this lambda carry the checked value up the composables chain?

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I am studying the [state in compose codelab](https://developer.android.com/codelabs/jetpack-compose-state#0) and I'm currently confused by how values are passed up through the composables lambda function parameters until the calling point. I'll explain;

First, I have a list item defined like this;

```
@Composable
fun WellnessTaskItemStateless(
taskName: String,
checked: Boolean,
onCheckedChange: (Boolean) -> Unit,
onClose: () -> Unit,
modifier: Modifier = Modifier
) {
Row(
    modifier = modifier, verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically
) {
    Text(
        modifier = Modifier
            .weight(1f)
            .padding(start = 16.dp),
        text = taskName
    )
    Checkbox(
        checked = checked,
        onCheckedChange = onCheckedChange
    )
    IconButton(onClick = onClose) {
        Icon(Icons.Filled.Close, contentDescription = "Close")
    }
   }
   }
```

The item above is called by another composable like below:

```
    @Composable
    fun WellnessTaskItem(taskName: String,onClose: () -> Unit,checked: 
    Boolean,onCheckedChange: (Boolean) -> Unit, modifier: Modifier = Modifier) {

    WellnessTaskItemStateless(
        taskName = taskName,
        checked = checked,
        onCheckedChange = onCheckedChange,
        onClose = onClose,
        modifier = modifier,
    )
    }
```

The item is passed as part of a Lazy List

```
    @Composable
    fun WellnessTasksList(
        list: List<WellnessTask>,
        onCloseTask:(WellnessTask) -> Unit,
        onCheckedChange: (WellnessTask,Boolean) -> Unit,
        modifier:Modifier = Modifier
    ) {
        LazyColumn(modifier = modifier){
            items(items = list, key = {task -> task.id}){ task ->
                WellnessTaskItem(taskName = task.label, onClose = {
                    onCloseTask(task)
                    },
                    checked = task.checked,
                    onCheckedChange = { checked -> onCheckedChange(task,checked) }
                                )
            }
        }
    }
```

It is at this point that I get confused, how does the `onCheckedChange` in `WellnessTasksList` get access to the current value of `checked` to be able to work with it in the lambda. I would've expected for there to be a point along the chain where we do something like `onCheckedChange(checked)` but that is not done. So when this happens
`onCheckedChange = { checked -> onCheckedChange(task,checked) }`

It works, but, I am not sure how it has the right value of checked to toggle the checkbox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The call to `Checkbox` will capture the state of the last value of `checked` and send the inverse of that value to the `onCheckedChanged` lambda.

See: https://cs.android.com/androidx/platform/frameworks/support/+/androidx-main:compose/material/material/src/commonMain/kotlin/androidx/compose/material/Checkbox.kt;l=96

In other words, the call,

```
Checkbox(
  checked = checked,
  onCheckedChange = onCheckedChange
)
```

will always call `onCheckedChange` with `!checked` whenever it detects a click on the checkbox and the call to `onCheckedChange` you expected is in the implementation of `Checkbox`.